# Is newrelic stopping my object from disposed?

Tags: windbg, newrelic

We are doing an exercise to understand the memory usage of our website. From windbg, we found this:

```
**0:000> !gcroot 000000020422c368
Thread 31e8:
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for NewRelic.Agent.Core.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for NewRelic.Agent.Core.dll
    000000000df1e7a0 000007fe9a9f90ae NewRelic.Agent.Core.ThreadProfiling.ThreadProfilingService.Aggregation_WaitCallback(System.Object)
        rsi: 
            ->  00000002ffb43a40 NewRelic.Agent.Core.ThreadProfiling.ThreadProfilingService
            ->  00000003ffb93858 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Agent
            ->  00000003ffb982b0 NewRelic.Agent.Core.DependencyInjection.WindsorContainer
            ->  00000003ffb982c8 Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer
            ->  00000003ffb98310 Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel
            ->  00000003ffb98558 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.ISubSystem, NewRelic.Agent.Core]]
            ->  00000003ffb99380 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.ISubSystem, NewRelic.Agent.Core]][]
            ->  00000003ffb99000 Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Naming.DefaultNamingSubSystem
            ->  00000003ffb990f8 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.IHandler, NewRelic.Agent.Core]]
            ->  00000002ffb17860 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.IHandler, NewRelic.Agent.Core]][]
            ->  00000003ffbad180 Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler
            ->  00000003ffbad278 Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager
            ->  00000002ffb22560 Castle.MicroKernel.Burden
            ->  00000001ffb4e160 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Transformers.SimpleSegmentTransformer
            ->  00000001ffb4d050 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Aggregators.MetricAggregator
            ->  00000001ffb4b450 NewRelic.Agent.Core.DataTransport.DataTransportService
            ->  00000001ffb48a18 NewRelic.Agent.Core.DataTransport.ConnectionManager
            ->  00000001ffb48840 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Time.Scheduler
            ->  00000001ffb488e8 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Action, mscorlib],[System.Threading.Timer, mscorlib]]
            ->  00000002ffb43458 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Action, mscorlib],[System.Threading.Timer, mscorlib]][]
            ->  00000001ffb4b9c8 System.Threading.Timer
            ->  00000001ffb4bae8 System.Threading.TimerHolder
            ->  00000001ffb4b9e8 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000002ffb432e0 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000002ffb40090 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000001ffb4ecd0 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000002ffb40d70 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000001ffb4d2b0 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000002ffb406f8 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000001ffd985a0 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000003ffdc8060 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000003ffcc85a8 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000003ffc02558 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000003ffc02e80 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000000ffb41b80 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000000ffb38f80 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000001ffaf06c8 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000003ffb19d88 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000003ffaffe38 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  00000003ffaffdd8 System.Threading.TimerCallback
            ->  00000003ffafe570 **System.Web.Caching.CacheExpires**
            ->  00000003ffafe4b8 System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle
            ->  00000003ffafe520 System.Collections.Hashtable
            ->  00000005320b3238 System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[]
            ->  000000020422c418 System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry
            ->  000000010359dfb8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[FinancialExpress.Analytics.WebSite.WebServices.SearchService+SectorItem, FinancialExpress.Analytics.WebSite]]
            ->  000000020420c698 System.Object[]
            ->  000000020422c368 FinancialExpress.Analytics.WebSite.WebServices.SearchService+SectorItem**
```

For me, this means this item was in cache, but expired now (as CacheExpires showed up). However, I am not sure why newrelic is showing up. Is it somehow newrelic is holding a reference of the object and stopping the object from relased?

Comment: daxu, did you ever get an answer to this?  I am finding the same thing in my out of memory crash dumps.. NewRelic is at the top of my GCRoot in a number of items in the heap.

Comment: Anything? I have same problem

Comment: @Ygalbel newrelic looked into this, but they don't think it is their product that stopping things from disposed. however, we couldn't find why it is showing up in windbg.

Comment: In our code too, I think new relic is not guilty, but I wanted to be sure from your experience. Thanks.